# Should I accept the answer?

Tags: support, bounties, unaccepted-answer

I asked a question—[set jquery ThickBox size to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16495069/1427849)—and I started a bounty. After the bounty period expired, there is no perfectly correct answer to what I am looking for, but one answer with two up-votes received +25 (half of my bounty amount). Should I accept this answer?

What will happen if I accept this answer or if I don't accept this answer?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work, "What is automatic awarding?". You don't have to accept the answer if it doesn't help you, but you should probably comment on it and explain why it does not help.

Answer (score 7):

If the answer isn't helpful to you, [you should not accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask):

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer ...

Answer (score 3):

> What will happen if I accept this answer or if I don't accept this answer?

The only visible difference will be different text color in the questions view: (white vs. yellow)

> [image]

- The question will **not** appear in the unanswered tab as it already have upvoted answer.
- There might be people who will notice there's no accepted answer and take a look vs. people who will skip the question if they see it already got accepted answer but it's really up to each user.
- Once upon a time there was "accept rate" showing on every question and having it too low caused lots of trouble but it's gone for good by now.